# subtracting from multiple datasets

Tags: reporting-services, scope, aggregate-functions

I have a requirement as follows:

```
Dataset1
Name1   count1 
asdf      11
werw      12 
fsafs     22
```

and another dateset

```
Dataset2 
Name2       Count2
pjljk        21
mljlk        33
jlkjlj       45
```

Now i need to have 3 tables in the report, table 1 shows data from dataset1,
table 2 shows data from dataset2 and table 3 shows the difference of count 
from dataset1 and dataset2.

I tried using expressions in table 3 but to use count1 and count2
i need to apply a scope and it won't allow me to use scope 
without an aggregate function.

How do i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

If possible, I suggest:

- combine the two datasets into a single dataset;
- replace the existing datasets in tables 1 and 2 on the report with the combined dataset, with a table-level filter to exclude the unwanted data in each table;
- populate the third table with the difference of the two counts from the combined datasource.

This assumes that both datasets can be combined (which should be possible if they are both from SQL queries from the same database).